# How to communicate between threads and equivalent for Waitforsingleobject()

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, waitforsingleobject

I am just starting C++ at school, and I'm trying to do both Linux and Windows. 
So here is my code and the exercise. The thing is I have no clue how to time the thread to run again, and whenever I run it I don't get the right char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>


using namespace std;
bool t;

#define NUM_THREADS  3

void *Saisie(void *PT)
{
    char TT[150];
    cout << "Entrez une chaîne de caractères :" <<endl;
    cin >> TT;
    t = true;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Visualisation(void *PT)
{
cout<<"La chaine transmise est :" <<  &*(char*)PT <<endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t TH1;
    pthread_t TH2;
    char TT[150];
    t = false;

    while (t == false){
        pthread_create(&TH1,NULL,Saisie,&TT);  // Création du thread TH1
        pthread_join(TH1,NULL);
    }
    if (t == true){
        pthread_create(&TH2,NULL,Visualisation,&TT);  // Création du thread TH2
        pthread_join(TH2,NULL);
    }

    cout << "\nFin du programme – saisir une lettre pour fermer\n";
    cin >> TT;
}
```

And my output is the following :

Entrez une chaîne de caractères : test 
La chaine transmise est :\250\365\277\357\376

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, the first one is why is my char TT not going properly into the 2nd thread.

Comment: And then, If the user doesn’t enter a char TT after 5 seconds, the pro- gram needs keep asking the user to enter a new char.

Comment: Please dont tell me your tutor is telling you to use `pthread`. `std::thread` has been part of standard c++ for over 6 years now...

Comment: There is a veritable toolkit for all of this in the standard I would [start with those tools](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)

Comment: She is actually telling us to use pthread. I had no clue of `std::thread` I'll take look at it then thank you !

Comment: do you know how to synchronize threads? Just including the pthread lib and creating threads is insufficient. Have you tried anything at all with the pthread library?

Answer (score 0):

synchronise your threads and use the  library provided by the C++ standard. That way your code is portable.

Using the pthread library is not more desirable than the above option. There is a pthread implementation for Windows but why go to that trouble when you can write just once using what the C++ standard provides.

To answer your specific query you can either use a **sleep** primitive or if you need to wait on a condition then use **condition variables**

Take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)